# Saving a streaming DataFrame to MongoDB using MongoSpark

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql

Some backstory: For a homework project for university we are tasked to implement an algorithm of choice in a scalable way. We chose to use Scala, Spark, MongoDB and Kafka as these were recommended during the course. To read data from our MongoDB, we opted to use MongoSpark as it allows for easy and scalable operations on data. We also use Kafka to simulate streaming from an outside source. We need to perform multiple operations on every entry that Kafka produces. The issue comes from saving the result of this data back to MongoDB.

We have the following code:

```
val streamDF = sparkSession
    .readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "aTopic")
    .load
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

From here on, we're at a loss. We cannot use a `.map` as MongoSpark only operates on DataFrames, Datasets and RDDs and is not serializable, and using `MongoSpark.save` does not work on streaming DataFrames like the one specified. We also cannot use the default MongoDB Scala driver as this conflicts with MongoSpark upon adding the dependency. Note that the rest of the algorithm heavily relies on joins and groupbys.

How can we get the data from here to our MongoDB?

Edit:
For an easy to reproduce example, one could try the following:

```
val streamDF = sparkSession
    .readStream
    .format("rate")
    .load
```

Adding a `.write` to that, which is required for `MongoSpark.save`, will cause an exception because write cannot be called on a streaming DataFrame.

Comment: Maybe you should post a reproducible example using something like an RDD queue DStream with your data. That would help reproduce and test a solution...

Comment: @ErnestKiwele is this okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Adding a .write to that, which is required for MongoSpark.save, will cause an exception because write cannot be called on a streaming DataFrame.

The `save()` method for [MongoDB Connector for Spark](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/) accepts RDD (as of current version 2.2). When utilising [DStream](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#discretized-streams-dstreams) with MongoSpark, you need to fetch the 'batches' of RDDs in the stream to write.

```scala
wordCounts.foreachRDD({ rdd =>
  import spark.implicits._
  val wordCounts = rdd.map({ case (word: String, count: Int)
          => WordCount(word, count) }).toDF()
  wordCounts.write.mode("append").mongo()
})
```

See also:

- [Design Patterns for using foreachRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#design-patterns-for-using-foreachrdd)
- [MongoDB: Spark Streaming](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/streaming/)